# In NBG, can a set contain a proper class?

Tags: set-theory

For example, I would want to consider the set of all classes Xi (for i a natural number), where Xi is the class of all sets of cardinality i.

Comment: No.${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. In $\sf NBG$ classes which are elements of other classes are sets. Moreover, you can think about this as a single sorted theory with only classes, then define the property of being a set as being an element of another class.

Comment: Thanks ! Is there perhaps another set theory that allows a set of classes ?

Comment: Hm I guess no because we would then be able to reproduce Russel's paradox

Comment: You can have that, this is called 2-classes or hyperclasses. But it's not going to produce sets out of nowhere. Just a hierarchy of sets, classes, 2-classes, and so on. Then you get type theory.